# react-chartjs-2 Line graph doesnt update with data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a class LineChart.js which contains this code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';


const data = {
    labels: ['red'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First Dataset',
      data: [65],
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
      tension: 0.1
    }]
  };

function LineChart() {
   
    return (

        <div>

            <h3>Hello</h3>

            <Line> 
                data = {data}
            </Line>

        </div>

    )
}

export default LineChart
```

I call this in another class by using:

```
    <div className={classes.chartContainer}>
                <LineChart></LineChart>
                </div>
```

When I run this code it shows me a text "Hello" and under it is a default graph, but no data has been processed. See image:
https://gyazo.com/312696275a57306c531d3872c75aa0d9

Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong? I'm seeing no weird error loggings.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be like this:

```
<Line data={data}/>
```

Given this small description
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2

Comment: ^ That's correct. More examples can be found in the `react-chartjs-2` docs here: https://react-chartjs-2.netlify.app/docs/working-with-datasets/